# How to use https for all pages

Tags: magento2, https, localhost

I wanted to use https for all pages.

For this I tried changing unsecured base URL to https in web configuration and in back-end.

But at that time,the page is not loading at all, error is "too many redirects"

I am running in localhost,but used servo to get forwarding and there by using https.

This is how my htaccess file looks like

```
<IfVersion < 2.4>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
Require all denied
</IfVersion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was to install https for localhost

here is a link to the tutorial I used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH6evGKgy20

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your .htacess file of your magento root:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

Now test the frontend it should work.

Comment: <IfVersion < 2.4>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all denied
</IfVersion>
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on Is this what you meant,or do we need tags ?

Comment: I get the following error 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gladius.serveo.net/magento3/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://gladius.serveo.net/magento3/pub/static/version1545123586/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: I am not able to open the url you have shared.

Comment: Its not an url,thats the error I get,I will paste the entire error in the next comment

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'gladius.serveo.net/magento3' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'gladius.serveo.net/magento3/pub/static/version1545123586/…'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Comment: Did you add the code I have suggested?

Comment: yes. after that came the error I mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess in apache

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Where do you make this change sir ? in httpd.conf ? I am using wamp server btw

Comment: Please use magento root .htaccess.

Comment: I recieve the following error Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gladius.serveo.net/magento3/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://gladius.serveo.net/magento3/pub/static/version1545127212/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: And further pages are not loaded